# Cannot add vertices or edges to CosmosDB Gremlin graph with Python SDK

Tags: python, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, tinkerpop, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I have a Cosmos DB instance running the Gremlin API, and I am using the Python SDK on 3.7.

Currently I am trying to build a graph that models papers with topics and authors, by having each object connected to the other. In my code I scrape the web for some papers, then model them like so:

```py
    insert_paper_query = '''g.addV('paper').property('id', '{}').property('title', '{}').property('abstract', '{}')
                            .property('time_processed', '{}').property('url', '{}').property('pk', '{}')'''.format(item['id'], item['title'], item['abstract'], time_processed, item['url'], item['id'])
    callback = paper_graph_client.submitAsync(insert_paper_query)
    print_status_attributes(callback.result())
    if callback.result() is not None:
        logging.info("Paper stored in Gremlin graph successfully: {}".format(new_paper))
        # Assess the author and topic vectors, then create edges between these vectors
        logging.info('Processing author vertices for paper {}'.format(item['id']))
        for author in item['authors']:
            add_author_query = "g.addV('author').property('name', '{}')".format(author)
            callback = paper_graph_client.submitAsync(add_author_query)
            add_author_edge_query = "g.V('{}').addE('authoredBy').to(g.V('{}'))".format(item['id'], author)
            callback = paper_graph_client.submitAsync(add_author_edge_query)
        logging.info('Processing topic vertices for paper {}'.format(item['id']))
```

The values that are being inserted are taken from the dictionary that models a paper, for example:

```json
{
  "id": "2161355c-8ac1-4b96-abde-e0c221b4c3b9",
  "title": "Some boring title",
  "abstract": "Some boring abstract",
  "time_processed": 1647210602,
  "url": "https://paperarchive.com",
  "authors": [
     "author1",
     "author2",
     "author3"
  ]
}
```

In theory this should work. I've tested these queries on the Azure Portal with some dummy data, and they work fine - the vertices and edges are added and connected as expected. Yet I run my code, nothing is added to the database. But there isn't any errors either - the code keeps running as if nothing happened. Even the callback object doesn't report anything amiss. I've double checked the connection and the queries, and everything is perfectly in order.

I'm really struggling to find the cause of why none of these queries work in python, but they are correct and do work on the portal. Am I just daft and missing something obvious, or is there something else wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered what the root cause of this was.

There were errors being thrown but, for some reason, they would not appear using the normal logging stack trace.

The root cause of this issue was the fact that I did not explicitly state the serializer when initialising my client object. The serializer defaulted to GraphSON v3, which is not currently supported by Cosmos DB.

Changing this to use V2 solved this problem:

```py
def authenticate_gremlin_client():
    paper_graph_client = client.Client('wss://<my database>.gremlin.cosmos.azure.com:443/','g', 
                                username="/dbs/publications/colls/papers", 
                                password="<my password>",
                                message_serializer=serializer.GraphSONSerializersV2d0())
    return paper_graph_client
```